# Can I destructure object refs in Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to destructure a reactive object into refs so I don't need to use the full object path to access them in the code/template.

Given an object like this:

```js
const exampleStuff = ref({ 
  house: { doors: 2, windows: 6 }, 
  car: { doors: 4, windows: 8 }
});

// ...and update the object to test reactivity
setTimeout(() => {
  exampleStuff.value = { 
    house: { doors: 1, windows: 5 }, 
    car: { doors: 2, windows: 6 } 
  };
}, 2000);
```

In this simplified example, I'd like to assign a variable, `car`, so that I can access its reactive value directly.

I tried a few things, and they didn't work as expected:

```js
// printing {{ car.windows }} in the template stays as 8,
// even when the value updates to 6
const car = exampleStuff.value.car;

// same if I wrap it in toRef: {{ car.windows }} stays as 8
const car = toRef(exampleStuff.value.car);
```

A computed getter does work, however:

```js
// printing {{ car.windows }} in the template updates from 8 to 6 as expected
const car = computed(() => exampleStuff.value.car);
```

I know computed getters would be the only solution in the Options API, but I thought there was a way to do this in the Composition API.

Is there a way to destructure objects with the Vue 3 Composition API, and keep their reactivity?

Comment: One way to do destructure reactive objects and maintain their reactivity is by using [toRefs()](https://dmitripavlutin.com/props-destructure-vue-composition/).

Comment: I thought so too, but defining `car` with `const { car } = toRefs(exampleStuff.value);` also doesn't update 8 to 6 in the template

Comment: No, because nested object references can change, referring them too early will make a ref for nested property invalid. computed is the proper way to do this. Especially when you need a read-only ref, you don't want to modify it accidentally, which toRef is capable of. You can write your own helper that will accept a path to nested property similarly to lodash.pick and do the same thing as in computed(). I'm not aware of an existing one

Comment: If that's the case @EstusFlask then it's the same as the Options API after all. The docs show a ref being destructured, but they don't mention what happens to its reactivity: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#caveat-when-unwrapping-in-templates And also they example they give is an object where the property is explicitly defined as a ref itself...

Comment: Options api doesn't have composition refs so this could be different, these are things that are fundamental that make it the same, this is not tied to vue reactivity. `var obj = { a: { b: 1 } }; var a = obj.a; obj.a = { b: 2 }`. a.b and obj.a.b are are completely unrelated at this point because obj.a !== a, this is the only way it can work in JS. And the only way you can keep the proper reference to b is to not access it too early, i.e do this inside a function, `getB = () => obj.a.b`, that's the role that a computed plays

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more reading and experimentation, I found a way to make this work.

## Replacing the object breaks reactivity

Crucially, my example would never work because I was replacing the whole object, and therefore its properties would be different references even if they had the same names.

Instead of:

```js
  // This replaces `exampleStuff` with a different object
  exampleStuff.value = { 
    house: { doors: 1, windows: 5 }, 
    car: { doors: 2, windows: 6 } 
  };
```

Update each property but keep the root object:

```js
  // This works because it keeps `exampleStuff`
  Object.assign(exampleStuff.value, { 
    house: { doors: 1, windows: 5 }, 
    car: { doors: 2, windows: 6 } 
  });
```

I had incorrectly assumed that updating the object ref with `.value` would do this automatically.

Note that the `house` and `car` properties are still being replaced in the exampleStuff root object.

Note that updating with the spread operator breaks reactivity for the same reason:

```js
  // This doesn't work because it replaces `exampleStuff`
  exampleStuff.value = {
    ...exampleStuff.value,
    ...{ 
      house: { doors: 1, windows: 5 }, 
      car: { doors: 2, windows: 6 } 
    }
  }
```

## Destructuring does work with `toRefs`

Once I fixed the way I was updating the object ref, a few of the destructuring techniques above did start to work:

```js
// This works
const { car } = toRefs(exampleStuff.value)

// This works too
const car = toRef(exampleStuff.value, 'car');

// This does not work: 
// It creates a reference to `car` in the original object,
// and `car` still gets replaced by the update with `Object.assign`
const car = toRef(exampleStuff.value.car);
```

Here's a working demo with the updated fixes on the [Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

And [here's a souped-up version of the demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) that demonstrates how incorrect usage of `toRef` could break reactivity.

Comment: It's my first time working with JS Proxy objects, so I had to change my way of thinking. Even though the object is accessible via `.value`, it's still considered the "root object" and so replacing it completely would break any references to specific properties.